# What is spatial information in Convolutional neural network?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

The architecture of the CNN model contains several convolutional layers, non-linear activations, batch normalization, and pooling layers. The initial layers learn the low-level concepts such as edges and colors and the later level layers learn the higher level concepts such as different objects.

At a lower level, the neurons contain information for a small region of the image, whereas at a higher level the neurons contain information for a large region of the image. Thus, as we add more layers, the size of the image keeps on decreasing and the number of channels keeps on increasing. The downsampling is done by the pooling layers.

For the case of image classification, we need to map the spatial tensor from the convolution layers to a fixed length vector. To do that, fully connected layers are used, which destroy all the spatial information.

For the task of semantic segmentation, we need to retain the spatial information, hence no fully connected layers are used. That’s why they are called fully convolutional networks.
Can anybody little bit elaborate that what is spatial information in CNN nd how it relates with FCN ?